# If $|z + \frac{1}{z}| = a$ where $a$ is a positive real number then why is $\frac{-a+\sqrt{a^2+4}}{2}\leq\lvert z\rvert\leq\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2+4}}{2}$?

Tags: complex-numbers

If $|z + \frac{1}{z}| = a$ where $a$ is a positive real number, then why is

$$\frac{-a+\sqrt{a^2+4}}{2}\leq\lvert z\rvert\leq\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2+4}}{2} \quad?$$

This is a formula in a list of formulae given in my book, and I was wondering how it was derived. How do I get this result? I refer to the chapter complex numbers of the book 39 years chapterwise topicwise solved papers by Arihant.

Comment: Note that these are not questions on Complex Analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint: }$$$$$ Use the polar form of $z$ by representing it as $re^{i\theta}$.

Also note that $|z|^2=z\bar z$.

Lastly note that $$|z|=|\bar z|=|-z|=|-\bar z|\Rightarrow \left|z+\dfrac 1z\right|=\left|\bar z+\dfrac 1{\bar z}\right|=\left|-\bar z-\dfrac 1{\bar z}\right|=\left|-z-\dfrac 1{z}\right|$$
$$$$ 
Hence, it suffices to consider only one of the numbers $z,\bar z, -\bar z, -z$, namely the one in the first quadrant. Therefore, let $z=re^{i\theta}, \theta\in[0,\pi/2]$
$$$$
Thus, $$\left|z+\dfrac 1z\right|=a\Rightarrow\left|r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)+\dfrac 1r(\cos\theta-i\sin\theta)\right|^2=a^2$$

$$\left(r\cos\theta+\dfrac 1r \cos\theta\right)^2+\left(r\sin\theta-\dfrac 1r \sin\theta\right)^2=a^2$$

After expanding, $$r^2+\dfrac 1{r^2} +2\cos2\theta=a^2$$
$$\left(r-\dfrac 1r\right)^2=a^2-4\cos^2\theta\le a^2$$
$$$$
Thus we want to maximize $a^2-4\cos^2\theta$ in order to find the maximum (and minimum) value of $\left(r-\dfrac1r\right)^2$. Now, $0\le|\cos\theta|\le 1\Rightarrow 0\le\cos^2\theta\le 1$. Hence, the maximum value of $\left(r-\dfrac1r\right)^2=a^2-4\cos^2\theta$ is $\left(r-\dfrac1r\right)^2=a^2$. Note that to simultaneously maximize (and minimize) $\left(r+\dfrac1r\right)$, we choose the maximum value of $a^2-4\cos^2\theta$ ie we let 
$$\left(r+\dfrac1r\right)^2=a^2$$

$$$$
$$$$
For $\theta=\dfrac\pi2$, $\left(r-\dfrac 1r\right)^2= a^2\Rightarrow \left(r-\dfrac 1r\right)= a$
$$\Rightarrow r^2-ar-1=0$$ which has roots $r=\dfrac{a\pm\sqrt{a^2+4}}{2}$ 
$$$$
$\textbf{To maximize r:}$
$$$$We ignore the negative root and assign $r$ the value $r=\dfrac{a+\sqrt{a^2+4}}{2}$

$$$$
Thus:$$r=\dfrac{a+\sqrt{a^2+4}}2$$ It follows that the greatest value of $|z|$ is attained at $$z=\left(\dfrac{a+\sqrt{a^2+4}}2\right)e^{i\pi/2}$$
Hence, $$|z|\le \dfrac{a+\sqrt{a^2+4}}2$$
$$$$
$\textbf{To minimize r:}$
$$$$We ignore the positive root and assign $r$ the value $r=\left|\dfrac{a-\sqrt{a^2+4}}{2}\right|=\dfrac{-a+\sqrt{a^2+4}}{2}$

Note that $ a\ge0\Rightarrow \sqrt{a^2+4}>a\Rightarrow a-\sqrt{a^2+4}<0 $. But $r\ge0$, hence we take the modulus.
$$$$

Comment: I have a doubt, when taking $ r - 1/r = a$ as you said I get a quadratic equation which gives both the values $a+√(a^2+4)/2$ and $a-√(a^2+4)/2$. And when I try to take the minimum value I get $ r - 1/r = √(a^2-4) $ which leads to the values $√(a^2-4)+a/2$ and $√(a^2-4)-a/2$. Please help me.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't really understand your doubt. Could you please explain again?

Comment: In the third step from the bottom why do we take only $a + √(a2+4)/2$  and not $a - √(a2+4)/2$ ? Also when we to take minimum value is the equation r−1/r=√(a2−4)? That  equation leads to some other results.

Comment: @Hema I have edited my answer to address your first doubt.

Comment: @Hema I'll look at your second doubt later...